# Problems when running nvcc from command line

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cuda, nvcc

I need to compile a cuda .cu file using nvcc from command line. The file is "vectorAdd_kernel.cu" and contains the following piece of code:

```
extern "C" __global__ void VecAdd_kernel(const float* A, const float* B, float* C, int N)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < N)
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

I used the following command (I need to get a .cubin file):

```
nvcc --cubin --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -keep -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" vectorAdd_kernel.cu
```

The compiler creates files vectorAdd_kernel.cpp4.ii and vectorAdd_kernel.cpp1.ii then it stops with the following output:

```
C:\Users\Massimo\Desktop\Pluto>nvcc --cubin --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 vectorAdd_kernel.cu -keep -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"

vectorAdd_kernel.cu

vectorAdd_kernel.cu

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(29): error: invalid redeclaration of type name "size_t"

C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include\new(51): error: first parameter of allocation function must be of type## Heading ## "size_t"

C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include\new(55): error: first parameter of allocation function must be of type "size_t"
```

Can you please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: What else is in the .cu file?  Why do you need to `-I` the VC/include path? Why do you need `--use-local-env` and `--cl-version`?

Answer (score 21):

I just encountered this in Visual Studio 2017 and Cuda v9.0 trying to compile from the command line with `nvcc`. After a lengthy session I realised my Visual Studio Command line tools were setup to use `cl.exe` from the `x86` director instead of the `x64`. There are a number of ways to resolve it, one way is to override the directory it looks for its compiler tools with - for example as in :

```
nvcc -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x64"  -o add_cuda add_cuda.cu
```

It then worked fine.

I'll also mention that I used the `which.exe` utility from the git tools to figure out what version of `cl.exe` it was accessing, but the `where` command - native to windows - works as well.

## Update:

Another way - probably a better way - to handle this is to just set the Visual Studio environment variables correctly to 64 bits like this for the Enterprise edition:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

For the Community edition substitute "Community" for "Enterprise" in the path.

You can also select the toolset with (for example) `--vcvars_ver=14.0` which selects the 14.0 toolset, necessary to compile CUDA 9.1 with the 15.5 version of Visual Studio.

Then you can build simply with this:

```
nvcc  -o add_cuda add_cuda.cu
```

Comment: Thanks, greate tip. After reading this I tried the VS17 x64 native tools command line prompt. Worked.

Comment: Another solution is to simply launch the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" from the start menu.

Comment: for me with CLION it is possible to choose different versions of visual studio. choose AMD64 set the same as this answer

Answer (score 3):

**VS Community 2019:**

Open a **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.3.6
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cd c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>nvcc hello_world.cu
hello_world.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>
```

If environment is not initialized for `x64` and you have opened **x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**, run:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.3.6
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cd c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>nvcc hello_world.cu
hello_world.cu

YOU GET LOT OF ERRORS ....

75 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/AFP/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00004504_00000000-12_hello_world.cpp1.ii".

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.3.6
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>nvcc hello_world.cu
hello_world.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

c:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\chapter03>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem.

The code where build breaks in SourceAnnotations.h :

```
#ifdef  _WIN64
typedef unsigned __int64    size_t;
#else
typedef _W64 unsigned int   size_t;
#endif
```

I've added `_WIN64` compiler symbol with this `--compiler-options "-D _WIN64"`. My nvcc build string looked like this:

```
nvcc kernel.cu --cubin --compiler-options "-D _WIN64"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the cause of the problem, or how this solution fixes it?